# Помогите разобраться как работает рекурсия

Tags: c#, рекурсия

Есть такой код:

```
public static bool canyougetthissum(int[] numbers, int k ,int index = 0)
        {
            if (k == 0)
                return true;
            if (index >= numbers.Length || k < numbers[index])
                return false;
            return canyougetthissum(numbers, index + 1, k - numbers[index]) || canyougetthissum(numbers, index + 3, k - numbers[index]);
        }
```

Я понимаю, что рекурсия вызывает сама себя и после того как получила false на n вызове, возвращается в вызов n-1. Но как работает последняя строчка:

```
return canyougetthissum(numbers, index + 1, k - numbers[index]) || canyougetthissum(numbers, index + 3, k - numbers[index]);
```

Они вызываются одновременно или пока первая из них не получит false, вторая не начнет работу?

Comment: Ну так добавьте в функцию какой нибудь вывод в лог или в консоль и проверьте.

Comment: _пока первая из них не получит false, вторая не начнет работу_